# How to style Material UI v5 Switch via Theme?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have implemented Material Switch according to my design but I have made a custom component and have styled it using styled and sx prop but I was wondering how to do it in theme itself so that when I import Switch from Mui I get my designed switch.

```
const CustomMuiSwitch = styled(Switch)(({ theme }: { theme: any }) => ({
  width: 28,
  height: 16,
  padding: 0,
  display: 'flex',
  margin: 'auto',
  '&:active': {
    '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
      width: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked': {
      transform: 'translateX(9px)',
    },
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
    padding: 2,
    '&.Mui-checked': {
      transform: 'translateX(12px)',
      color: '#fff',
      '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#00A1E0',
      },
    },
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
    boxShadow: '0 2px 4px 0 rgb(0 35 11 / 20%)',
    width: 12,
    height: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    transition: theme?.transitions?.create(['width'], {
      duration: 200,
    }),
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
    borderRadius: 16 / 2,
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
  },
}));
```

[image]

And this is what I tried to style it in theme itself but I was not able to do it.

```
const theme = createTheme({
    MuiSwitch: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          ':active': {
            '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
              width: 12,
            },
            '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked': {
              transform: 'translateX(9px)',
            },
          },
        },
        thumb: {
          boxShadow: '0 2px 4px 0 rgb(0 35 11 / 20%)',
          width: 12,
          height: 12,
          borderRadius: 6,
          transition: 'width 200',
          ':active': {
            width: 12,
          },
        },
        track: {
          borderRadius: 16 / 2,
          opacity: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
        },
        switchBase: {
          padding: 2,
          ':checked': {
            transform: 'translateX(12px)',
            color: '#fff',
            '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
              opacity: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#00A1E0',
            },
          },
          '.Mui-checked': {
            transform: 'translateX(9px)',
          },
        },
        checked: {
          transform: 'translateX(12px)',
          color: '#fff',
          '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
            opacity: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#00A1E0',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[image]

I am just confused about the checked and active state and how to target classes within these pseudo-class. Any Mui experts can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the overall `components` top-level property for your `createTheme()` call. There's also a few things off in your CSS but overall it's almost there:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          width: 28,
          height: 16,
          padding: 0,
          display: "flex",
          margin: "auto",
          "&:active": {
            "& .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
              width: 12,
            },
            "& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked": {
              transform: "translateX(9px)",
            },
          },
        },
        thumb: {
          boxShadow: "0 2px 4px 0 rgb(0 35 11 / 20%)",
          width: 12,
          height: 12,
          borderRadius: 6,
          transition: "width 200",
        },
        track: {
          borderRadius: 16 / 2,
          opacity: 1,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)",
        },
        switchBase: {
          padding: 2,
          "&.Mui-checked": {
            transform: "translateX(12px)",
            color: "#fff",
            "& + .MuiSwitch-track": {
              opacity: 1,
              backgroundColor: "#00A1E0",
            },
          },
          "& .Mui-checked": {
            transform: "translateX(9px)",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-switches-4gzen4) where you can see the styled switch is no longer needed.